# form containing user control not hiding

Tags: c#-4.0, user-controls

I am facing some form hiding problem.

Actually I have a form with a user control on it. the user control has submit button, and when I click it I want the user control as well as the form containing it to be vanished. 
I can use this.hide(), but it is only hiding the user control and not the form.

I create a

```
         form1 f1 = new form1();
         f1.hide();
```

and even tried

```
       f1.close(),
```

but nothing is working.
Please help

EDIT:
this is the actual code:

```
  Input inp = new Input();
            inp.Show();
```

it is where the call the input form. In its loading event, I call the usinput user control.

```
                USinput usinp = new USinput();
```

then in the submit button in the user control, the use the following code:

```
         Input inpt = new Input();
            inpt.Hide();
            this.Hide();
            Companies co = new Companies();
            co.Show();
```

It shows the new form and the user control is gone, but the input form is still there.

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tried with that code only?
- Have you made sure that your control isn't called `f1` and has no name conflict?
- Is your control class name form1?

It is definitly something around that.

EDIT: 
Your problem is on the first line here.

Input inpt = new Input();
        inpt.Hide();
        this.Hide();
        Companies co = new Companies();
        co.Show();

In your UserControl, you create a new form. So you have 2 forms! The second one is never made visible though. You have to send to the UserControl a reference to the form. That way, you always use the same form.

Here's how to create the UserControl from the form:

```
USinput usinp = new USinput(this); //Will send a reference of the form to the control
```

The constructor of your control will look like this:

```
private Form parentForm;
public USinput(Input parentForm)
{
    this.parentForm = parentForm;
}
```

And your submit button code will contain this:

```
parentForm.hide();
```

Comment: hi there, there is no name conflict as I only use form1 as an example here.my form name is input and the user control it has is named usinput.

Comment: Please provide the full code of the method where you code appears. It may provide more info. Also, by defaul a newly instantiated form is set to visible = false. So unless you do f1.show, it won't show up.

Comment: @saumyavishnoi I edited my answer. If it helps, don't forget to vote up / mark as answer.

Comment: at parentForm.hide(); , I am getting an error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: That means there's something you haven't copied properly from my given code. It works fine. Do you have a default constructor on your UserControl? And do you add the control to your form programmatically or by the form designer?